# JSON integrity check triggers "table or view does not exist"

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

When running run the following SQL in `Oracle 19`, it works well:

```
alter table X add constraint C1 check ("XX" is not null)
```

But, if I run the SQL below:

```
alter table X add constraint C2 check ("XX" is json)
```

I get the following error, with no other info:

> ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The column type is CLOB , the table is empty, and it only has two columns: ID and XX. I tried to change the column name but it did not help.
There are other tables in the same schema with working JSON constrains, but I fail to spot any difference.

Has anyone run into a similar problem?

Comment: quite strange. I just ran the commands you posted and I did not have any issue ( oracle 19c ).  create table X ( id number, xx clob ); alter table X add constraint C1 check ("XX" is not null) ;alter table X add constraint C2 check ("XX" is json) ; -- all good on 19c

Comment: enable a trace over the session to see what happens. you should get more details regarding the recursive sql error

Comment: Please post your complete `create table` statement

Comment: It is a very simple table [ create table X(ID number, XX clob) ]. We have to dig deeper into the logs. Thanks!

Comment: Check to see if you have a DDL trigger defined at schema or database level. An error in there would yield a "recursive" error such as that

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it's a bug with Oracle 19 (Bug 30871716).
It has been fixed in July 2020, in version 19.8.0.0.200714.